# Отображение коллекции Page - C# WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

Есть у меня класс TechnicalCard, есть page TechnicalInfoPage для ввода/вывода экземпляров класса (в конструкторе можно передать этот экземпляр).
Есть Window, на котором выводится некоторая инфа, в том числе коллекция TechnicalCard + кнопка для добавления экземпляров в коллекцию.

Как это реализовать?
Вот примерно набросал такое:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsControl Name="icTechnicalCards">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame Content="{Binding}"
                               Margin="5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

            <Button Name="btAddTechnicalCard"
                    Content="+" Padding="5"
                    FontSize="28" FontWeight="Black"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Click="btAddTechnicalCard_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

В коде:

```
window.icTechnicalCards.ItemsSource = order.TechnicalCards.ToList().ConvertAll(x => new TechnicalInfoPage(x));
```

Но при попытке потом `window.ShowDialog();` вылетает исключение `"Родительским объектом для страницы Page может быть только Window или Frame"`, так я ведь и использую Frame...
Вот что примерно хочу получить:[image: Эскиз]
*Дополнение:*
Что интересно, если размещать не Page, а ее содержимое, то всё отрабатывает нормально:

```
icTechnicalCards.ItemsSource = order.TechnicalCards.ConvertAll(x => new TechnicalInfoPage(x).Content);
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сисетема `Page/Frame` костыльна и ничего с этим не поделать, в итоге `Page` заменил на `ContentControl` и всё заработало как надо